# Where do we need to include non business logic validations in Service Layer

Tags: enterprise-architecture, programming-logic, service

Currently um working in an application and it has the following hierarchy

WEB API2 Controllers (hilds the end points)

Business Logic Layer (Dedicated for business logic handling )

Data Access Layer (Repositories)

If we want to impose a validation which does not related to a business logic as for an example a character count validation for a specific field in an entity , what will be the ideal place to implement it?

Some says it should be on Controller it self , but I cannot agree with it .

Comment: Who imposes a restriction on the character count if the restriction doesn't come from the business rules/business logic?

Comment: Some believes business logic should address only business related logic , character count limit is independent from the business logic , it's because of the restrictions imposed by the technology and the users . um in the verge of two dilemma. Some argues a presence of an object module layer might solve the issue  and it's been identified as an anti pattern by some experts . I know this sounds wired @BartvanIngenSchenau

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no hard and fast rules. But usual place to implement is in the business logic layer. Also I think that field size validations are business logic.

If you use a rich domain model you should implement validation in the entities. But if you don't have a rich domain model and the only interface you provide to the outside world is via your web API I don't think there is anything wrong with doing validations there.

If there is a front-end app I would duplicate the validation logic there as well to give better UX and save the network call.

Answer (score 0):

I think that always depends, I know that DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) rule is very strong and powerful, but at any price?
There is also another rule ["fail fast"](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/fail-fast-principle/)

If the validation is really simple (as checking a string is empty or less than X characters) then I don't think is a harm to check it in different places.
Also there exist the rule "fail fast", so why to continue spending time in our CPU, eventually connections, memory, etc...